# Visual Studio 2010 - Debug Breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive just created a new web site project , added a few lines of code in my .cs file set a break point, and nada, website works, but debug point is not hit.
Any ideas?

Im starting the project with Debugging, running on windows 7 64bit

thanks

Comment: ...and you are certain that the code line would be hit?

Comment: Add breakpoint to Load event handler.

Comment: If your web sites works, you might not placed your debugging point were it will be hit ie.,the line you have break point would not have been used to render your page.

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS or the built-in web server? Is the breakpoint showing up as a solid red circle while running, or an open one? We need more information.

Comment: break point is in the page load event, using the built in web server

Comment: Is the breakpoint a solid Red circle or a transparent circle with a red border when you are on that page in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging with edit and continue in .net while running 64 bit code is not possible. Switch to forced x86 to start debugging.

Comment: Wah?! News to me... - Since 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184678(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in debug mode? Check out the configuration under project properties -> build, make sure it is running under "any cpu" and with debug configuration

Answer (score 0):

Are you running VS as Administrator? If not Try Run As Administrator option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled debug in the web.config? If so you have to have debug true as below. Normally VS asks to enable debug at the first time if you are trying to run in debug mode.
[image]

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
```

Comment: Write below where you want to debug and see...

To use the Debug class, simply add the “using System.Diagnostics;” statement to your C# code file, and call Debug.Write:

Debug.Write("Hello, Debugger!");